# C# Get child property from the item of Parent Collection

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I have a parent:

```
public class ReportFilterBuilderStruct
{
    public string PropName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string SubListName { get; set; }
    //public virtual string SecondaryPropName { get; set; }

    public ReportFilterBuilderStruct(string inpPropName, string inpClassName, string inpSubListName)
    {
        PropName = inpPropName;
        ClassName = inpClassName;
        SubListName = inpSubListName;
    }
}
```

And a child:

```
public class DateReportFilterBuilderStruct : ReportFilterBuilderStruct
{
    public string SecondaryPropName { get; set; }

    public DateReportFilterBuilderStruct(string inpPropName, string inpSecondaryPropName, string inpClassName, string inpSubListName) : base(inpPropName, inpClassName, inpSubListName)
    {
        SecondaryPropName = inpSecondaryPropName;
    }
}
```

}

It will be used in my view to store some data about my model class property.
`editorListProp` will store both `ReportFilterBuilderStruct` and `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`, that is why it is a `List` of parent class objects.

```
var editorListProp = new List<NTStock.Models.ReportFilterBuilderStruct>();
```

Now i want to access them:

```
if (subItem.GetType() == typeof(NTStock.Models.ReportFilterBuilderStruct))
{
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        @Html.DisplayName(subItem.PropName)
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center  mb-2">
        @Html.Editor(subItem.PropName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = subItem.ClassName } })
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        @Html.DisplayName(subItem.PropName)
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center mb-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            From:
            @Html.Editor(subItem.PropName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = subItem.ClassName } })
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            Till:
            @Html.Editor(subItem.SecondaryPropName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = subItem.ClassName } })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

So the point is, that I can't access my `SecondaryPropName`, even though I made sure that current `subItem` is definetly of type `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast `subItem` to `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`, for example:

```
((DateReportFilterBuilderStruct)subItem).SecondaryPropName
```

Comment: The second part of the answer is unfortunately not true, because `is` will return `true` even if the `subItem` is of type `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`, as it inherits from `ReportFilterBuilderStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

This approach would work in a dynamically typed language like Python, but not in C#. Your list is of type `List<ReportFilterBuilderStruct>`. When you access an item from the list, e.g. `list[0]`, you get back an object of type `ReportFilterBuilderStruct`, even if you stored a `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct` there and `GetType()` correctly returns `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`.

In the `else` branch you will first have to cast the item to `DateReportFilterBuilderStruct`:

```
else
{
    @{ var dateReport = (DateReportFilterBuilderStruct)subItem; }
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        @Html.DisplayName(dateReport.PropName)
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center mb-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            From:
            @Html.Editor(dateReport.PropName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = dateReport.ClassName } })
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            Till:
            @Html.Editor(dateReport.SecondaryPropName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = dateReport.ClassName } })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```